# biblatex-dw bibliography custom formatting

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

I need to do some custom modification to the bibliography.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,
    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

@book{b2,
    year = {2014},
    title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
    address = {Leipzig},
    edition = {1},
    publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
    isbn = {386583888X},
    editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
    shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{b2} text.
    text \footcite{b2} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would like to change the following things:

1. The first red square: all authors should be separated by slashes. I managed to do it for the last author with DefineBibliographyStrings, but I couldnt find out how to do it for more authors
2. The second red square: the separator before the location should be a dot, not a comma

Many thanks for the help!

[image: bibliography]

Comment: The delimiter of the authors is stored in `\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}`

Comment: Any reason why you add a space before the editors-string (`editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}`)?

Comment: no reason at all, just weird formatting :)

Comment: I would not use `page={},` to suppress the page prefix, `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` should work just fine, maybe in combination with `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manipulation of `and` isn't the correct way.

Use the following:

ad 1 -- adding slashes

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\let\finalnamedelim\multinamedelim
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\let\bibfinalnamedelim\bibmultinamedelim
```

ad 2:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

Hints:

- Don't use spaces inside `\DefineBibliographyStrings`

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{Hg\adddot}} ,
    editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\let\finalnamedelim\multinamedelim
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\let\bibfinalnamedelim\bibmultinamedelim

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

@book{b2,
    year = {2014},
    title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
    address = {Leipzig},
    edition = {1},
    publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
    isbn = {386583888X},
    editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
    shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{b2} text.
    text \footcite{b2} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any use in retaining the `\finalandcomma` in the `final` delimiters. Additionally, if the `final` delimiter should not have special handling I would just set it to be `\multinamedelim`, same with the `bib` versions. So I would cut down the first block to `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}`

Comment: Ad 2) I would use `\addperiod` instead of `\adddot` (even though the OP said 'dot'; periods are full stops, dots end abbreviations). I also don't like to start bibmacros with punctuation commands, but accept that it is probably the smoothest course of action here.

Comment: @moewe: ad1: I used the shorter form, thanks. ad2: I know what you mean, however in this case it's the easiest way.

Comment: @moewe the solution for ad 2 kills the edsuper=true option in biblatex-dw, i.e. it does not print the edition in superscript anymore, it rather does not print it at all. Do you have an idea how to have the edition printed as superscript and still use this solution?

Comment: @Philipp Please ask a new question about that. I hope I'll be able to fix it, but certainly not in the comments here.

Comment: I guess the follow-up question is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437563/35864