# book biblatex-dw bibliography formatting - dot before address instead of comma

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I would like to have a dot instead of a comma before the rendering of the address field of bibliography entries. See image below, where I have marked the commas that should be replaced by dots.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{b2,
    year = {2014},
    title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
    address = {Leipzig},
    edition = {1},
    publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
    isbn = {386583888X},
    editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
    shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
}
@Book{geyer2004,
    Title                    = {Religion und Nation, Nation und Religion: Beiträge zu einer unbewältigten Geschichte},
    Address                  = {Göttingen},
    Editor                   = {Geyer, Michael and Lehmann, Hartmut},
    Gender                   = {pm},
    ISBN                     = {3892446687},
    Number                   = {3},
    Series                   = {Bausteine zu einer Europäischen Religionsgeschichte im Zeitalter der Säkularisierung},
    Shorttitle               = {Religion},
    Year                     = {2004}
}
@Book{beiderwiedenhelge1995,
    Title                    = {VHKM},
    Address                  = {Rostock},
    Editor                   = {{Bei der Wieden, Helge}},
    Gender                   = {sm},
    Number                   = {8},
    Shorttitle               = {Veröffentlichungen},
    Year                     = {1995}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\mkbibnamegiven}
%
% all authors should be separated by slashes in bib and cites
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\citemultinamedelim}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace
        {\addcomma\addspace}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options.

1. Redefine `\newunitpunct`. This can potentially affect more places than just the punctuation before the publisher block. This might or might not be desired. In the example entries no other places are affected.

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
   ```
2. Redefine `publisher+location+date` to add a period at the beginning.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
     \ifbool{bbx:origfields}
       {\ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
         {\iffieldundef{origyear}
           {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
           {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
         {\iflistundef{origlocation}
           {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
             {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
           {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {\blxdw@warning{%
                Field 'origlocation' is set, but 'origdate' is 
                \MessageBreak%
                empty at entry '\abx@field@entrykey'.
                The 'orig' fields \MessageBreak are omitted
                for this entry}%
              \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
             {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}}}
       {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}
   \makeatother
   ```
3. Use [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch/) to add `\setunit{\addperiod\space}` to `publisher+location+date` (credits go to [@gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105447/gusbrs) [for suggesting this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437563/book-biblatex-dw-bibliography-formatting-dot-before-address-instead-of-comma/437565?noredirect=1#comment1098001_437565))

   ```
   \usepackage{xpatch}
   \xpretobibmacro{publisher+location+date}
     {\setunit{\addperiod\space}}
     {}{}
   ```

Comment: +1 I'd go for 2, though. Btw, wouldn't this be a nice example of the convenience of `\xpretobibmacro`?

Comment: Thanks @moewe, where do I find these template definitions usually, and how do you determine which one to edit?

Comment: @gusbrs You know I usually don't use `xpatch` unless i have to modify drivers. But it makes good sense here. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Philipp This one lives in `authortitle-dw.bbx`, but `standard-dw.bbx` is also relevant. Additionally `biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx` and a few other files can also contain some definitions. Usually I just follow the definitions starting from the bibliography drivers.